# How do I get available projects (TFS 2015 extension) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, plugins, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to write a plugin for TFS 2015 (its important). I read a couple of manuals. the examples all turns out simply, but it is more difficult with a real plugin. my problems:

1) i cant get available projects for current user

2) i cant check is the curren user admin (his permissions)

in tfs 2013 i received this information from get request, for example:
http://myTFSServ:8080/tfs/_api/_common/GetCollectionJumpList?__v=5&navigationContextPackage=%7B%22Action%22%3A%22index%22%2C%22Area%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Level%22%3A8%2C%22Controller%22%3A%22workItems%22%7D&selectedHostId=6e60eeec-39b3-4902-a864-172cd27dea91

but in tfs 2015 i cant do this.

how can i get available projects and get permissions for current(or not) user?

Answer (score 0):

**To  get available projects for current user**

It's easy to use rest API to achieve what you want:

[Get a list of team projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#get-a-list-of-team-projects)

- *Get all team projects in the project collection that the authenticated user 
  has access to.*

`GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version={version}[&stateFilter{string}&$top={integer}&skip={integer}]`

However for using **javascript** , there is no related [API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/rest-clients).

**To get a user's permission**

Neither tfs rest API nor rest client could achieve it.  You could directly use *tf command* or through UI (web portal). How to programmatically get permissions for a user, you could refer this link: [Extracting-effective-permissions-from-TFS](https://github.com/ALM-Rangers/Extracting-effective-permissions-from-TFS) from ALM Rangers project on *GitHub*